# Preventing Copy Paste to another system

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, teamviewer

I gave a remote access to one freelancer i hired so that i do not have to transfer the files, but he smartly used copy paste through team viewer and took away the data by the time I realize, i read on many from to follow this path in team viewer - 
extras>>options>>advanced....and stop clipboard synchronization, but still the copy paste is not stopped.

What are the alternative solution so that no one can copy data from my desktop to his through team viewer.

Comment: Anything digitized can be copied.

Comment: You just disabled clipboard synchronization on your end not his end, he would have to disable it, create a user without read permissions to the files.  If you provide the person access to the files, they can be copied, in more ways then can be listed.

Comment: TeamViewer is a powerful aid to cooperative access, but has many features, such as clipboard synchronisation and file transfer which are unsuitable for an uncooperative user. Whatever else you may use (Windows Remote Desktop, VNC, etc), he could still copy information to shared network or cloud files, or take a local snapshot of the remote screen. You should consider whether he could work with a limited and controlled subset of your files by sharing them, either on the same network or by using cloud synchronisation with the likes of DropBox, GoogleDrive, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Clipboard synchronisation is under the `Advanced settings for connections to other computers`. The teamviewer filemanager is what you need to stop.

You can do so by doing the following:

1. Open your Teamviewer
2. Go to menu `Extras` -> `Options`
3. Go to `Advanced`
4. Press <kbd>Show advanced options</kbd>

Under `Advanced settings for connections to this computer`

5. Change Access Control to `Custom Settings`
6. Press <kbd>Configure...</kbd>
7. Change all things you want to disabled to Denied, such as `Transfer files`, `File transfer using the file box` and `Control the local TeamViewer`

You can deny other permissions or set them to ask if you want, but ask is not going to be handy if the computer is set to unattended access.

Note that this will prevent the user from copying the files through TeamViewer. Any other service, such as uploading to the internet, transferring to an FTP server using an FTP client, etc. can still be used if the user is smart enough and has the rights to such tools.